# How to take screenshot of HtML div content & save as PdF file in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am making a web application in PHP and javascript. I have a form in which user fill their details & they can mail it, the user details should be mail in PDF file.
For this I want to take screenshot of particular div in my form with content 7 save it in to PDF file.

OR copy the content of HTML div & past back to already present PDF file using javascript.
Please help me, if u have any alternate way please suggest it to me.

Comment: Take a look at [jsPDF](http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to print any part of page you can use `print` function. It takes DOM as argument, parse it, and prints it. (by printing you can convert it to PDF).

For example if you run the following code under Stackoverflow's scope, you can print the specified div:

```
print($(".post-text"));
```

[image]

I'm affraid there is no good functionality in Javascript to covert DOM to PDF. You can try [flying-saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//). You might also want to send DOM's contents to a PHP page, convert it to PDF, and return data.

And in order to take screenshots you can use [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the prompt response. ut Ihave a issue this doesnt seem to print nly the div that i specify. seems to be an issue with double quotes i guess. this is my line of code.  <input type="button" name="Printbtn" value="Print" onClick="print($('.content span12'));">  Any helpwill be greatly appreciated.Thank you